# How can I have 2 columns of bullets?

Tags: itemize

I would really like something like

```
* First Bullet   * third Bullet
* Second Bullet  * Fourth Bullet
```

I've tried using `tabular` and `itemize`, but `\item` does not show the bullet.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157300/how-to-left-align-text-in-two-column-itemize) might help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`multicol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package:

```
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{-2.1in}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item one
      \item two
      \item three
      \item four
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Where `\columnsep` can be used to reduce the spacing between columns if you don't have enough text in the bullets to fill up the space. Otherwise it will look ugly!